# Loop command in Interpolation

Tags: plotting, interpolation, procedural-programming, command-line

I have a following interpolation function `A[x,y]` defined below. The variable `y` has some fixed range which is different for each `x`. Now, while doing interpolation and further making a contour plot Mathematica is not restricting the bound of y given in interpolation command, rather it is maximizing the range of `y` for all `x`, e.g., maximum allowed value of `y` is `0.76` for `x=0`, while it is `0.7442` for `x=0.2`. 
How, I can make a contour plot with different maximum value for `y` for each individual `x`.

Thanking you in advance.

```
ClearAll;
A := Interpolation[{{{0, 0}, 84.82}, {{0, 0.1}, 84.53}, {{0, 0.2}, 
83.68}, {{0, 0.3}, 82.22}, {{0, 4}, 80.12}, {{0, 0.5}, 
77.28}, {{0, 0.6}, 73.58}, {{0, 0.7}, 68.7}, {{0, 0.76}, 
64.2}, {{0.2, 0.0}, 84.63}, {{0.2, 0.1}, 84.3}, {{0.2, 0.2}, 
83.4}, {{0.2, 0.3}, 81.9}, {{0.2, 0.4}, 79.86}, {{0.2, 0.5}, 
76.9}, {{0.2, 0.6}, 73.16}, {{0.2, 0.7}, 68.05}, {{0.2, 0.7442}, 
65.12}, {{0.5, 0.0}, 83.56}, {{0.5, 0.1}, 83.25}, {{0.5, 0.2}, 
82.3}, {{0.5, 0.3}, 80.70}, {{0.5, 0.4}, 78.32}, {{0.5, 0.5}, 
74.9}, {{0.5, 0.6}, 70.0}, {{0.5, 0.61}, 68.6637}}, 
InterpolationOrder -> 3]

A[0.5, 0.4]

ContourPlot[A[x, y], {x, 0, 0.5}, {y, 0, 0.7}]
```

Comment: You can use `RegionFunction` to restrict the region that is drawn

Comment: `InterpolationgFunction` gives you the valid domain for `x` and `y` variables. In your case, this is `{{0,0.5},{0,0.4}}`, so MMA extrapolates beyond these values if you increase the plotting domain...I would use `ContourPlot[A[x, y], {x, 0, 0.5}, {y, 0, 0.4}]`, or as @NikiEstner suggest...

Comment: should point 5 be `{0, 0.4}` ?

Answer (score 1):

extract the convex hull of the grid points from the interpolation function:

```
   ch = ConvexHullMesh[A["Grid"]];
```

use as region function:

```
   ContourPlot[A[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
           RegionFunction :> (RegionMember[ch, {#1, #2}] &)]
```

[image]

Note I fixed that point from `4` to `.4` per comment.

Comment: You can also do it with `ContourPlot[A[x, y], {x, y} ∈ A["ElementMesh"]]`